# When an IP address in *new* table is overwritten?

Tags: network, peer-discovery

I'm reading the address management of Bitcoin core implementation. There is one thing I couldn't understand is in which condition an IP address in the *new* table of a node is overwritten?

In particular, when the node hears about a new peer, it adds that IP address into a slot in the *new* table, if that slot is occupied, it checks if the existing *isTerrible*: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/addrman.cpp#L309

```
if (infoExisting.IsTerrible() || (infoExisting.nRefCount > 1 && pinfo->nRefCount == 0))
```

What is nRefCount? What is the idea behind this check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nRefCount indicates the number of slots in the *new* table that is occupied by the same IP address.